# Do any of the PSD to HTML sites work?

Tags: html, psd

Hi I am skeptical about uploading my .PSD files to one of these websites that claim to convert .PSD to .HTML for you easily.

How do these work? Do they generate ALL of the necessary CSS?

Comment: My question is an honest one, just because I don't know the answer doesn't mean I need to get downrated. Lol. Grow up

Comment: Yes, but your question not really programming-related.

Answer (score 3):

They might be able to make HTML, but can they make clean, efficient HTML. Nope.

Are they smart enough to recognise a menu and use an unordered list, instead of a bunch of  DIVs? Nope. Does it know when an image should be a background behind text, or when text should be merged with the background? Are they smart enough to save portions of the artwork as PNG vs. JPG?

This task is far too complex to automate. It's like when you have a MS WORD doc and save it as HTML - you get HTML, but it's full of clutter and superfluous mark-up is 10x larger than it need be. It works, but it's crap.